# How to built algorithm that can generate random set of digits and letters

Tags: algorithm

On what language is more easy to code that kind of algorithm and make it more flexible to changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy to do, at least in widely used programming languages that I'm aware of (e.g. C++, Java, etc).

1. Store all possible characters in an ordered collection like array or a string. For example, you can make a string that contains all letters and digits like so:

   ```
   // Exact syntax depends on your programming language.
   //
   // I used a string for simplicity here but some languages don't allow
   // you to access individual string characters so you'll need an array.
   //
   string a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
   ```
2. Generate a random number between `0` and `length(a) - 1` (size of your character set array minus one).
3. Use the number you generated as an index and extract the character from the array at that index.
4. Congratulations! You've just generated one random character from your character set. Go back to step #2 and repeat `N - 1` times (`N` is here the total number of characters you want to generate).